# Find max Dataset of multiple columns in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I EF Core I have to find the max dataset of a table:

```
IQueryable<Measurement> dbMeasuringsExisting = dbContext.Measurements;
int iMaxId = dbMeasuringsExisting.Max(meas => (int?)meas.MessID) ?? 0;
```

In SQL this produces a simple

```
SELECT MAX(MessId) FROM Measurement
```

statement. This works if `MessID` is unique but in my case it is possible that I have several records with that max `MessId`.

So I have to find the MAX Id of several columns.

Example:

```
| MessId | IdCol2 | 
| 1      | 10     |
| 2      | 20     |
| 3      |  2     |
| 3      |  1     |
```

I want to get 3 and 2 as `Max(MessId, IdCol2)`: Get Max of MessId and then Max of IdCol2

How is that possible with one single query? And if not - how to do it as performant as possible? ;-)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You want to group by MessId before you take the max, then take the max of the groups by key, then the max of the grouped values.

Comment: That's the actual question? The wording is contradictory and without the entities (EF deals with entities, not tables) and sample input and output, we can only guess. It looks like you want to retrieve the *row* with the largest value along multiple columns. You don't need `MAX` for that, you can use `SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER By MessId Desc,IdCol2 DESC`. The equivalent in LINQ would be `ctx.Measurements.OrderByDescending(m=>new {m.MessId??0, m.Whatever}).Take(1)`

Comment: If you want to retrieve specific columns only, add a `.Select()` before `Take(1)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, thats what I want to do: Select a row with the largest value along multiple columns. I see that the OrderByDescending-Method would work for me but does is still perform with millions of records? Yes, I can put an index on these columns. Does the Db "know" that  it only needs to query the first row instead of getting and sorting through everything?

Comment: You can check what the database knows by checking a query's execution plan. Both ordering and MAX depend on indexes. If all the columns you want are covered by an index, the query will be fast.